# If x of y values are equivalent

Tags: c#, java, math, if-statement, conditional-statements

If I have 5 integers (a,b,c,d,e) what is the shortest way I can check if ***at least*** 3 of them are equivalent.

ex.

```
a==1
b==1
c==2
d==3
e==4
//returns false

ex.
a==1
b==1
c==1
d==3
e==4
//returns true
```

Comment: What do you mean by fastest? Are you worried about performance here?

Comment: Nah, I just didn't want a massive for loop... A better phrasing should have been "What is the shortest way to check if..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for all cases:

```
bool match = array.GroupBy(n => n).Any(g => g.Count() >= 3);
```

Comment: Just to pick a little...isn't `Any` better than `Max`? Don't really need to check the largest group, just check if one of them has 3 or more elements.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano You are correct.  I'll edit the change in, thanks.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin care to explain?

Comment: +1. @galuano1 - Max would have to check all groups, when Any stops on first successful result - so potentially checking less groups. In your 5 element sample it does not matter, but if you have 100+ items/groups it may.